# Absolute value size! (\lvert doesn't scale)

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath

Everyone seems to ask about this and the usual solution seems to be to use \lvert and \rvert with the amsmath package, but that doesn't work for me either.

example:

```
f_{3,2} = \left(\sqrt{13}-2-\lvert \frac{\sqrt{13}}{6}+2-2\sqrt{7}\left(1+\delta V\right)\rvert\right)/4
```

Here's what I get

[image]

I want the absolute value bars to scale taller in accordance with the content.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can scale then with `\left\lvert` and `\right\rvert`, just as with parentheses.

```
f_{3,2} = \left(\sqrt{13} - 2 - \left\lvert \frac{\sqrt{13}}{6} + 2
- 2\sqrt{7}\left(1 + \delta V\right) \right\rvert \right)/4
```

If you load the `mathtools` package, you can use a `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command which simplifies scaling delimiters: writing `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}` defines two commands: `\abs`, which delimits its argument with `\lvert` and `\rvert`, and `\abs*`, which does the same, but scaling it automatically.

Here's what this would look like for your code.

```
% in preamble
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

% document
f_{3,2} = \paren*{\sqrt{13} - 2 - \abs*{\frac{\sqrt{13}}{6} + 2
- 2\sqrt{7}\paren*{1 + \delta V}}}/4
```

Comment: Even better use mathtools and it's `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` to make `\abs{} ` (i think it is even an example in the manual). It gives you a simpler interface to use.

Comment: My god. Thank you Arun. But why god does LaTeX need "\left" and "\lvert" (with an "l" for left!)? Makes no sense. Either way, this has been causing me problems forever, so thanks!

Comment: @daleif: oops, while you wrote that I was editing in an answer to use that. Thanks for pointing it out, though!

Comment: @Steve: the l and r in `\lvert` and `\rvert` indicate "spacing as a left delimiter" and "spacing as a right delimiter," respectively. I agree it's counterintuitive, but there are times where I want the correct spacing, but to not scale the delimiters, such as `$\abs{A_j}$` in text mode (if the delimiters scaled with the subscript, it would make the line too tall). So it's nice to have both options.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, that actually makes sense! I was thinking \lvert and \rvert would be essentially identical since the symbol itself is horizontally symmetric, but I'm guessing this means that the two symbols are actually different in the amount of blank space on the left and right sides of the symbol--which makes sense.

Comment: You might want to add an example using manual scaling, the abs of a sum is usually a good example

Comment: @Steve try `|-1|` vs `\lvert -1\rvert` then you will see the significance